# FreeIPA on Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: amazon-ec2, sssd, freeipa, amazon-linux

I want to install the FreeIPA client on Amazon Linux 2023.

Unfortunately, Amazon Linux 2023 doesn't officially support the package.
As a workaround I installed the Fedora repositories and managed to Install the freeipa-client package, but during installation I get the following error while trying to onboard the host with an OTP.

```
DEBUG stderr=SASL Bind failed
    Invalid credentials

2023-09-21T07:50:26Z ERROR Joining realm failed: SASL Bind failed
    Invalid credentials
```

I also tried to directly download and rpm install the required binaries but I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/ipa-client-install", line 22, in <module>
    from ipaclient.install import ipa_client_install
ImportError: cannot import name 'ipa_client_install' from 'ipaclient.install' (unknown location)
```

Has anyone managed to install the FreeIPA client and successfully onboard the host to the IPA domain? Do you know another workaround that it will allow me to have HBAC/RBAC capabilities from FreeIPA but without the FreeIPA agent?

Comment: You might try with the srpm packages instead of the pre-compiled - but expect to have to untangle a lot of dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a firewall issue after all.

I uninstalled the packages and installed them through the default yum repos.
Firewall needs to be disabled or properly configured on the targeted IPA server (it was reactivated after reboot even though it was disabled)

Also the OTP for onboarding a new host needs to be considered strong with upper and lowercase characters, numbers and special symbols, at 12 characters it worked.